# React Navigation Global FAB

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, floating-action-button

I am using react-navigation v5 and ended up with `App.js` like this

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => (
  <NavigationNativeContainer>
    <MainStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        header: () => <AppbarHeader />,
      }}
    >
      <MainStack.Screen name="index" component={index} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="alternate" component={alternate} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  </NavigationNativeContainer>
);
```

I would like to add a Floating Action(FAB) Button that would be visible on the bottom of both the `index` and `alternate` page that would allow the user to show a Modal that is currently omitted. Right now I feel like the only solution is to put my FAB component inside both the `index` and `alternate` components but this doesn't seem right because it shouldn't re-render and transition in with the page. It should float above the page transition. I feel like it should be more of a global navigator of some sort but I am not sure how that should work with the existing StackNavigator shown above.

I am Looking forward to any solutions provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @satya164 noted, you can put FAB in your root component. In addition, to [access to navigation actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/app-containers.html#calling-dispatch-or-navigate-on-app-container), you can use a ref to your navigation container.

```
const App = () =>{
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  return (
  <>
    <NavigationNativeContainer ref={ref}>
      // ...
    </NavigationNativeContainer>
    <FAB onPress={() => ref.current && ref.current.navigate('A SCREEN')}/>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it to be global, put it in your root component and not inside a screen.

```js
const App = () => (
  <>
    <NavigationNativeContainer>
      // ...
    </NavigationNativeContainer>
    <FAB />
  </>
);
```

Comment: Hi @satya164, This was one of my first thoughts as well. The problem is you can't access the navigation/useNavigation

Comment: @Mike Check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/app-containers.html#calling-dispatch-or-navigate-on-app-container

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo that looks like what I needed. Do you want to submit an answer? I will test it out and mark it accepted.